# Java project running on Glassfish: connection refused HTTP error

Tags: java, glassfish

This is my very first question on this site so hope not to bother any of you.
I do know there's a similar question made already, but at the same time there's only one answer to it which didn't work for me.

I am working on this University project pretty simple, but I have no experience programming with Java language. Now I have this code with a GlassFish server 4.1 which is running all good. However, when I try to run my project itself, I get the errors below.

I'm getting the following error:
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException:
        HTTP transport error:
            java.net.SocketException:
                Connection reset

[Here you can see my Output errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYymD.png)

Comment: There are so so so many things this could be.  Usually on this site we ask for a code snippet so that others can reproduce the issue.  In this case it could be a proxy issue, it could be as simple as the server you are trying to connect to is down, the server's hostname and/or port could be configured incorrectly in your code base.

Comment: On top of this we don't know what Java framework you are using (if any) what Java version, nor do we have any information on what or who you are trying to connect to.  All of the above would start moving you in the right direction.

Comment: notAChance, ty for answering, I appreciate your feedback for future questions. Now, I am not using any framework for this project. Actually I thought on adding part of my code that has something to do with the mentioned Output errors when I started my question, nonetheless it triggers many specific parts of my code so I thought it was going to be harder for you to kinda imagine my problem. Think the problem can be more oriented to a Proxy issue as I previously had to deal with something similar but in C# projects.